# How to retrieve all children of a parent record?

Tags: mysql, select, hierarchy

I have one MySQL table with this columns:

```
id
father
son
street
city
```

I want to obtain all descendants of a father recorded, how I can do this?

I tried this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE filhos AS (
select login, loginpatrocinador from pedido where login<>"" and loginpatrocinador="logindapesquisaaqui"
UNION 
select f.login, f.loginpatrocinador from pedido as f, filhos as a where a.login<>"" and   f.loginpatrocinador=a.login
)
SELECT * FROM filhos;
```

doesn't work...

Comment: Please, questions in this site must be written in English, translate it or move this question to the Portuguese site. Thank you

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)